# Intellij Font color does not change

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

Im trying to change the color of the font in IntelliJ but I can't seem to find how go into setting -> appearance -> theme and it changes the look of IntelliJ and some of the font changes like the color of text Strings and keywords like import but not the color of methods and variables a more

They just stay all the same color until is somehow use it for example if I declare the variable B like this

int B;

The color does not change.

But if I do

int B = 1; it does change to the color is supposed to be

See the picture I added [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6I62.png)

I also tried settings -> editor -> color scheme

Comment: Do you have IntelliSense? I only know this behavior when no SDK has been loaded yet.

Comment: in the image posted I don't see the example int B that you metnion